# How to generate a PKG CONFIG file when building libevent from source?

Tags: linux, build, compilation, pkg-config, libevent

I'm building libevent from source with the following set of commands on Linux.

```
export LDFLAGS="-march=x86-64 -L/home/me/locals/lib64/zlib-1.2.11-gcc-9.3.0/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-march=x86-64 -I/home/me/locals/lib64/zlib-1.2.11-gcc-9.3.0/include"

../configure --prefix=/home/me/locals/lib64/libevent-2.1.12-gcc-9.3.0

# Finally
make
make install
```

And this seems to be working. But I don't see anything related to generating package PKG_CONFIG files (*.pc)? How can I do that?

I have also the following active:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/locals/lib/pkgconfig
```

Comment: Isn't a pc file 4 lines of text?

Comment: They are multiple files and I think the intention is to not write anything by hand :) I have found them under: `/home/me/locals/lib64/libevent-2.1.12-gcc-9.3.0/lib/pkgconfig`. So I just copied them to my global `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` location.

Comment: Can you do `../configure --prefix=/home/me/locals` ? Then you don't have to do the copying.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Probably will work. What happens if I have multiple libevent libraries, I need to have different version tags in there, I’m not sure pkg-config supports that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer actually came from @Philippe.

I didn't realise that the installation directory for the lib is also where the `pkgconfig` folder is placed, containing the `*.pc` files.

So if one installs the libs into one massive repo location such as `~/locals/libs`, the `pkgconfig` folder will be placed in `~/locals/libs/pkgconfig` and all the `*.pc` files will be stored there. This is one of the approaches. If such an approach is chosen, the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` will look like this:

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=~/locals/libs/pkgconfig`

There is another approach, where you can build your libs in their version tagged locations. In that case one will need to construct and handle the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable in a more granular way. For example, the variable might look like this:

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/me/locals/lib64/libevent-2.1.12/lib/pkgconfig:/home/me/locals/lib64/ncurses-6.2/lib/pkgconfig`

Here is the detailed answer I got on the libevent's github issues page.

[Do I have the option of generating package config (*.pc) files when building from source?](https://github.com/libevent/libevent/issues/1215)